# Apple MFI for InHouse distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, external-accessory

we are developing an app that needs to communicate with external devices (through USB and BT) and I have doubts about the terms of MFI. The fact is that this app will be distributed through InHouse distribution and I don't know if enrolling to MFI is required for this kind of distribution or it's only when you want to distribute an app through the AppStore.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the terms and conditions of the MFI program. It should be asked at Apple's support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES, if you are developing the MFi accessory. Please read the following FAQ taken from [Apple](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#3-5)

**My company/organization wants to develop MFi accessories for in-house use. Do I need to join the MFi Program?**

> Yes. If you would like access to the MFi technical specifications and/or sample quantities of licensed components for development purposes, please apply for the MFi Development License. 
>   After License execution, you can work with an MFi Manufacturing Licensee who will manufacture the accessory and take responsibility for all program requirements on your company's behalf. 
>   To access the list of authorized MFi Manufacturing Licensees, click here.

NO, if you are only developing an app that communicates with external accessory. See FAQ below:

**I want to develop an iOS app that communicates with an MFi accessory. Do I need to join the MFi Program?**

> No. iOS app developers do not need to join the MFi Program. 
>   Everything app developers need is in the External Accessory Framework, which is provided in the iOS SDK. To access the iOS SDK, please join the iOS Developer Program: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/.